# ImageView parallax effect using accelerometer sensor is slow

Tags: java, android, performance, bitmap

I created a class called ParallaxController to create a parallax effect on three different imageviews with different speeds. This class uses accelerometer sensor and moves images with different speeds in the 'x' axis. My problem is with the performance, I load images in the imageviews via an AsyncTask class - [Android Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) - The problem occurs when I use 3 large images in imageviews , when I move the device imageviews move very slowly.

My Codes :

-ParallaxController.java :

```
public class ParallaxController {
private Activity context;
private View viewBack, viewTop, viewFront;
private float backSpeed, topSpeed, frontSpeed;
private float maxMove;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private ParallaxSensorEventListener eventListener;

public ParallaxController(Activity context, View viewBack, View viewTop, View viewFront, float backSpeed, float topSpeed, float frontSpeed, float maxMove) {
    this.context = context;
    this.viewBack = viewBack;
    this.viewTop = viewTop;
    this.viewFront = viewFront;
    this.backSpeed = backSpeed;
    this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
    this.frontSpeed = frontSpeed;
    this.maxMove = maxMove;
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    eventListener = new ParallaxSensorEventListener();
}

public void startControl() {
    sensorManager.registerListener(eventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

public void stopControl() {
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(eventListener);
}

private class ParallaxSensorEventListener implements SensorEventListener {

    float lastPitch = 0;

    public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        float pitch;
        if (isTablet(context)) {
            pitch = sensorEvent.values[2];
        } else {
            pitch = sensorEvent.values[1];
        }


        if (pitch > 45 || pitch < -45)
            return;

        float dp = pitch - lastPitch;
        if (dp == 0)
            return;
        float move = (dp * maxMove) / -45.0f;
        float maxSpeed = Math.max(backSpeed, Math.max(frontSpeed, topSpeed));

        Display display=context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size=new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        float backX = (move / maxSpeed) * backSpeed;
        float topX = (move / maxSpeed) * topSpeed;
        float frontX = (move / maxSpeed) * frontSpeed;

        if (viewBack != null) {
            float backSpace=(viewBack.getWidth()*(viewBack.getScaleX()-1))/2;
            if (viewBack.getX() + backX-backSpace > 0 || viewBack.getX() + backX +viewBack.getWidth()+backSpace < size.x)
                return;
        } else backX=0;

        if (viewFront != null) {
            float frontSpace=(viewFront.getWidth()*(viewFront.getScaleX()-1))/2;
            if (viewFront.getX() + frontX - frontSpace> 0  || viewFront.getX() + frontX +viewFront.getWidth()+frontSpace < size.x)
                return;
        } else frontX=0;


        if (viewTop != null) {
            float topSpace=(viewTop.getWidth()*(viewTop.getScaleX()-1))/2;
            if (viewTop.getX() + topX - topSpace > 0 || viewTop.getX() + topX +viewTop.getWidth()+topSpace < size.x)
                return;
        } else topX=0;

        if (backX!=0) viewBack.setX(viewBack.getX() + backX);
        if (frontX!=0) viewFront.setX(viewFront.getX() + frontX);
        if (topX!=0) viewTop.setX(viewTop.getX() + topX);

        lastPitch = pitch;
        Log.d("TAG",viewBack.getX()+"");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ParallaxController pc;
private ImageView iv_0;
private ImageView iv_1;
private ImageView iv_2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv_0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_0);
    iv_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_1);
    iv_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_2);

    setImage(iv_0, R.drawable.a);
    setImage(iv_1, R.drawable.b);
    setImage(iv_2, R.drawable.c);

    scale(iv_0, 1.4f);
    scale(iv_1, 1.4f);
    scale(iv_2, 1.4f);

    pc = new ParallaxController(this,iv_0,iv_1,iv_2, 1 , 3 , 5 , 250);
    pc.startControl();
}

private void setImage(ImageView iv, int res){
    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(iv);
    task.execute(res);
}

private void scale(View view,float scale){
    view.setScaleX(scale);
    view.setScaleY(scale);
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
     ...
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iv_0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iv_1"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iv_2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Note: The Activity is Always LandScape.

Thanks ... :)

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem? Can I suggest you to try loading the images using Glide?